# What is a better method to use to output mysql(PDO) results to HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

Started learning PHP about 3-weeks ago and am now working through database connections and queries. My question involves a chapter programming teaching point. Although I'm not able to test my code the research I've done on this site led me to code the following general query using while loop. However the book explains and is teaching something different. is one method better than the other or do both accomplish the same objective which is to pull the data from the db and output to HTML tables?

Also, I believe I learn more here than any book. The opinions and teachings are valued.

This is what I have:

```
<?php
        /set connection parameter variables
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'richardweb';
$password = 'richardchocolate';
$dbname = 'richard_ricardo_assignment_db';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$hostname", $username, $password);

//set mysql query

$sql = 'SELECT studentID, name, email 
        FROM student
        ORDER BY studentID';

$qry = $conn->query($sql);

$qry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$hostname"; $username, $password);

        $sql = 'SELECT studentID, name, email 
                FROM student
                ORDER BY studentID';
        $qry = $conn->query($sql);
        $qry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo "Error connecting to the database" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="main">

    <h1>Students</h1>
    <table class="table1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = $qry->fetchALL(); ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['studentID'])?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['name'])?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['email'])?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

This is what my book covers for displaying results in HTML Table. Only showing the tabular data output. I'm only giving the example from the book and have not converted my code. 

<?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['productName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['listPrice']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of exactly what you're asking, but `while ($row = $qry->fetchALL();` is not a good idea. `fetchAll()` does, in fact, fetch all. So that loop will execute only once, and `$row` will actually be many rows.

Comment: many of the examples and questions I've found here use the first method in my original question. I was just wanting to know the preferred method of logic.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm certain many of them do use `while ($row = $qry->fetch())...`, but I really don't think you'll find many that use `while ($row = $qry->fetchAll())...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have successfully executed a PDO statement, there are two main ways to fetch the results.

1. One at a time - This is typically done in a while loop, using one of the methods of `PDOStatement` that fetches data from ONE row from the result set, such as `fetch()`, `fetchColumn()`, or `fetchObject()`, like this:

   ```
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      // do something with data from each row
   }
   ```
2. All at once. For this, you will use `fetchAll()` and then typically use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the array of rows.

   ```
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
   foreach ($rows as $row) {
       // do something with data from each row
   }
   ```

Neither one is inherently better than the other. Which one you should choose depends on what you need to do with the data. For something like simply creating an HTML table to display the results, using the "one at a time" approach should be sufficient.

One reasonable use of `fetchAll()` is if you need to do multiple different things with your results at different points in your program. If you use the "one at a time" approach, you will need to execute your query repeatedly, which is typically less efficient.

But when using fetchAll, be sure to heed this warning (from the PHP documentation):

> Using this method to fetch large result sets will result in a heavy demand on system and possibly network resources. Rather than retrieving all of the data and manipulating it in PHP, consider using the database server to manipulate the result sets. For example, use the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses in SQL to restrict results before retrieving and processing them with PHP.

Comment: Excellent points and much appreciated. I find it strange the book resource guides me into using only one method. Although it covers both fetch() and fetchAll() there is no explanation like the one you provided why use one over the other.